# How to stop code and put another code if button is submit in the same file

Tags: php, button, logic, submit

I have a foreach loop and I want to execute always except when a button clicked and then echo something else in the spot that foreach was...I have tried these but none of them work right!

```
    if (!isset($_POST['myBtn'])) {
        foreach($postarray as $p){
            echo $p->postmarkup();
        }
    } else {
        echo $search_output; //this is the echo that i want to replace the foreach if the button is clicked.
    }
```

OR this

```
    if (isset($_POST['myBtn'])) {
        foreach($postarray as $p){
            echo $p->postmarkup();
        }
        exit();     
        echo $search_output;
    }
```

and  I have tried with many other ways but I could not find it... I know that these code are completely wrong :P I am sorry for this, just wanna give you an example to understand what my problem is. If anyone know this ..free to ask :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
foreach($postarray as $p){
    if (!isset($_POST['myBtn'])) {
        echo $p->postmarkup();
    }else{
       echo $search_output;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it outputs the foreach but when i search something and hit the button it outputs the else and the foreach...its similar to my examples.

Comment: so you dont want the loop to output anything if you hit the botton? i can't understand the problem

Comment: i want the loop to output the markup() (some html code) ...e.g. 5 posts in a row that take from db... now when i type in search box and click the button i want to remove the foreach and output something else there.. all these in the same page!

Comment: you can't do it with php, php runs the whole code first then it outputs it, its a server language, you need client language, like javascript to do it, i'm not so good at js so i can't help you much